# Test if exception is thrown from a function that accepts user input

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, input, mocking

For an assignment I am trying to test whether a ValueError exception is raised depending on user input

Here is my program that I am testing:

```
def prompt_num_integers():
    while True:
        try:
            # converting to int raises ValueError if input can't convert
            num_of_integers = int(input("How many integers do you want to store: "))
            if num_of_integers < 1:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't quite understand that.")
            continue
        else:
            return num_of_integers


def prompt_integers():
    # prompt user for number of integers then store that value into a variable
    num_of_integers = prompt_num_integers()
    # list for storing the integers
    integer_list = []
    # integer for keeping count of current num of integers
    x = 0
    while x < num_of_integers:
        try:
            # check if current num of integer equals total num of integers wanted, then give appropriate prompt
            if x == num_of_integers - 1:
                integer = int(input("Input last integer: "))
            else:
                integer = int(input("Input integer: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't quite understand that.")
            continue
        else:
            # add correct integer to integer list, then update current num of integers variable
            integer_list.append(integer)
            x += 1

    print(f"List of integers: {integer_list}")
    return integer_list
```

And here is my unit test:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

import GatheringInputFunctionsKing as Test


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a_function_throws_exception(self):
        with mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[0,1,1]):
            self.assertRaises(ValueError, Test.prompt_integers)
```

Even when testing just the function prompt_num_integers, I get the same result... The test just results with FAILED:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\PycharmProjects\CIS289_Module1\Test_GatheringInputFunctions.py", line 10, in test_a_function_throws_exception
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, Test.prompt_integers)
AssertionError: ValueError not raised by prompt_integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ValueError est caught inside prompt_num_integers as soon as it is raised, therefore, it will never be propagated to upper callers, and your test fails.
This version of the function for example makes your test green.

```
def prompt_num_integers():
    while True:
        # converting to int raises ValueError if input can't convert
        num_of_integers = int(input("How many integers do you want to store: "))
        if num_of_integers < 1:
            print("Sorry, I didn't quite understand that.")
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return num_of_integers
```